# Remove the child node from selected parent but not grand children

Tags: c#, xml

anyone please help me to remove inner xml tag
  where i want to delete fn-group and fn id tag
  but i want its child p , p and emphasis tag should be retained

here is my sample xml file

```
     <table-wrap-foot>
     <fn-group type="footnotes">
     <fn id="c89520-1-12">
     <p>
     <emphasis type="italic">Note</emphasis>:
     In 1300, of the twenty-two cities in Italy that had populations over 20,000.
     </p>
     </fn>
     </fn-group>
     </table-wrap-foot>
     </table-wrap>
```

here is my C# code

```
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDocument.Load("sample.xml");
        XmlNodeList xmlnode = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("table-wrap-foot");

        for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
         {
             if(xmlnode[i].InnerXml.Contains("<label>"))
             {  
             }
             else
             {
                 #here i want to delete //fn-group and fn but not p tag
             }
             }
        myXmlDocument.Save("sample.xml");
```

where i want to delete fn-group and fn id tag
        but i want its child p , p and emphasis tag should be retained
        here is my sample xml file
            Thanks
            Appu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Linq-To-Xml:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
XElement fnGroup = root.Descendants("fn-group").First(); // or .Element("fn-group"); if fn-group is a child of root
fnGroup.Parent.Add(fnGroup.Element("fn").Elements());    
fnGroup.Remove();
root.Save(file);
```

Result:

```
<table-wrap-foot>
  <p>
    <emphasis type="italic">Note</emphasis>:
        In 1300, of the twenty-two cities in Italy that had populations over 20,000.
  </p>
</table-wrap-foot>
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine now...why is not work with using xml package...here i have some modification work,  first i want to check table-warp-foot tag then i check other tag and remove,..

Answer (score 0):

You can select `<fn-group>` and remove it from the parent node, and then select `<p>` and add it to the parent node to make it retained (`null` checking skipped for brevity) :

```
XmlNodeList xmlnode = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("table-wrap-foot");
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlnode)
{
    if (node.InnerXml.Contains("<label>"))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        var fnGroup = node.SelectSingleNode(".//fn-group");
        var p = node.SelectSingleNode(".//p");
        //remove <fn-group> from it's parent
        node.RemoveChild(fnGroup);
        //append <p> to <table-wrap-foot>
        node.AppendChild(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: when executing above code i get null value for  var fnGroup and p